# iphone : embed Safari (like a "frame") within a native iphone application

Tags: iphone, safari, embed

Is it possible to embed Safari within a native application ? Not only lauching Safari but during the navigation, the user could access some buttons of the native application?

Just as if Safari would appear in a kind of a "frame" of the native application.

If it's possible, how could this be done ?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Fabio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey Fabio, i think what you might be looking for is the UIWebView.

As described: UIWebView Provides a view to embed web content. A UIWebView object can be attached to a window, and sent requests to load web content. This class can also be used to move back and forward in the history of webpages, and set some web content properties programmatically.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) project. It provides facilities to create an application embedding an UIWebView, so you can create an application using HTML/CSS/Javascript...